# const и перегрузка operator[]

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Вопрос касается перегрузки `operator[]`, а именно различия в создании константной и неконстантной версии. В большинстве случаев это будет выглядеть так:

```
T& operator[](size_t i);
const T& operator[](size_t i) const;
```

У меня есть несколько теоретических вопросов. Практически всегда сам вызов `operator[]` не модифицирует объект, а значит даже неконстантную версию стоило бы объявить как const-метод.

Первый вопрос: правильно ли я понимаю, что мы не объявляем его const-методом только потому, что хотим, чтобы эти методы не конфликтовали, и чтобы при обращении к элементу некоторого константного класса вызывался второй вариант перегруженного оператора?

Второй вопрос: верно ли, что если объект будет неконстантный, для него при вызове `operator[]` всегда будет вызываться первая перегруженная версия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Практически всегда сам вызов `operator[]` не модифицирует объект

Зависит от семантики. Например, `std::map`, `std::unordered_map` вообще не имеют `const` версий этого оператора, по той причине, что вызов с несуществующим ранее ключом приводит к созданию нового элемента в контейнере (явное изменение объекта).

Пара, описанных в вопросе сигнатур (с некоторыми нюансами) используется в стандартной библиотеке для `std::basic_string`, `std::vector`, `std::deque`, `std::bitset`, `std::array`, `std::valarray`. Т.е. константная версия возвращает константную ссылку (кроме `bitset`, он возвращает `bool` по значению), а неконстантная, соответственно, обычную ссылку на элемент контейнера. У `std::valarray`, кстати, есть [несколько пар перегрузок](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_at) с разными типами параметров, но это уже другая история.

Есть и типы, имеющие только константную версию оператора. Это `std::basic_string_view`, `std::reverse_iterator`, `std::move_iterator` и `std::match_results`. Отсутствие обычной версии обусловлено необходимость доступа *только-для-чтения* к членам-данным объекта.

Но есть и более необычные ситуации, например, для `std::unique_ptr` и `std::shared_ptr`, когда они владеют массивами объектов. Например, в `std::unique_ptr` объявлена [такая сигнатура](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_at):

```
T& operator[](size_t i) const;
```

Т.е. функция константная (не меняет своих членов-данных), но при этом возвращает неконстантую ссылку на объект, которым управляет указатель, и т.о. этот объект может быть изменен. Иначе бы просто сама концепция "умных" указателей была бы не так полезна.

> мы не объявляем его const-методом только потому, что хотим, чтобы эти методы не конфликтовали

В частности, да. Это ограничение механизма перегрузки. Если функция останется константной, то она должна будет принимать уже какой-то другой тип в качестве параметра. Т.к. по возвращаемым типам перегрузка не работает. Но и из-за иной  ситуации, уже описанной в другом ответе, когда функция константа, то и все члены-данные объекта `this` в этой функции константы. Чтобы можно было вернуть что-то неконстантное в этом ситуации, надо возвращать либо копию по значению, либо добавлять косвенности, как это сделано в "умных" указателях. Ведь указатель, который нельзя менять не запрещает менять данные, расположенные по адресу, хранимом в указателе.

> верно ли, что если объект будет неконстантный, для него при вызове operator[] всегда будет вызываться первая перегруженная версия?

Верно, но ничто не мешает сделать `const_cast` приведение, добавляющее `const`. Можно явно, а можно и через передачу в функцию, принимающую константную ссылку. В обратную же сторону (снятие `const`) приведение стоит делать с большей осторожностью.

Answer (score 5):

*"неконстантную версию стоило бы объявить как const-метод"*

Вы пробовали? Ведь если ваш объект - константный, как вы сможете вернуть неконстантную ссылку на константный объект?

Грубо -

```
class Test
{
    int& operator[](int i) const { return data[i]; }
private:
    int data[10];
};
```

Ведь в этом случае `data` тоже становится *константным*.

Если бы это было возможно - тем самым была бы дыра, позволяющая законно изменять константный объект...

Comment: Точно... спасибо большое)

Comment: @Abyx А это немного другое - в этом случае поле (указатель data) не меняется. В этом варианте можно и `int&` вернуть...

Comment: ну все мы знаем грязные хаки на основе кастов) так что можно хоть вообще всё делать константами... только не забудьте поставить volatile чтобы компилятор сильно не испортил картину